tessbridge.cpp:5:10: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory #include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
I'm building a Fiber Go application that uses the gosseract package for OCR. While Tesseract works perfectly from the command line, the application fails to compile with the following error:
github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2
tessbridge.cpp:5:10: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

What I Have Tried
Tesseract Installation:
Installed Tesseract from the UB Mannheim Tesseract page.
Verified that Tesseract works by running tesseract --version and processing images from the command line.
What additional steps do I need to take to resolve the leptonica/allheaders.h missing error when using the gosseract library in my Go application?

Check https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract/issues/234 too
